# CommunityToolKit.Mvvm updateing IsEnable button property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My view model contains a command. It should be executable when two TextBoxes are filled with input. My problem is that this button doesn't enable when I fill those two TextBoxes.

This is my command binded with button.

```
private AsyncRelayCommand? _createFileButton;
public IAsyncRelayCommand CreateFileButton => _createFileButton ??= new AsyncRelayCommand(OnCreateFile);
```

```
<Button Grid.Row="4" 
        Style="{StaticResource BlueButtonStyle}"
        Content="Create file"
        Command="{Binding CreateFileButton}"
        Margin="0,10,0,0"
        Height="25"/>
```

I have marked my function with property [RelayCommand]

```
[RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(ValuesAreNotEmpty))]
private async Task OnCreateFile()
{
   ...
}
```

And this is function which decide if button can be executed

```
private bool ValuesAreNotEmpty()
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringA)
        && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringB);
}
```

I am almost sure I have done something wrong but I can't find which part I messed up.
I've tried using `private ICommand CreateFileButton = new RelayCommand(OnCreateFile, ValuesAreNotEmpty)` like I used to write button commands but it require older nugget `GalaSoft`. I would like to use this new approach with `[ObservableProperty]`.

Comment: The RelayCommand attribute generates a command named `OnCreateFileCommand`. There is no need to create another command property named `CreateFileButton`. See the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/relaycommand

Comment: @Clemens oh I see. But how can I bind the button with property from generated class?

Comment: `Command="{Binding OnCreateFileCommand}"` does not work? It is a generated property, not a generated class.

Comment: You should mark stringA and stringB with with `[ObservableProperty]`, and use StringA and StringB in `ValuesAreNotEmpty` instead. That will ensure NotifyPorpertyChanged is called.

Comment: @Clemens Unfortunately not. Error says `OnCreateFileCommand property not found on object of type {MyViewModel}`. But When I create property `CreateFileCommand` in MyViewModel then error appears `Ambiguity between...`

Comment: You either have the property generated by RelayCommand or declare your own, not both at the same time. For the self-declared property of type RelayCommand you have to change the method signature to `public void OnCreateFile()`.

Comment: @PalleDue Yes, I did mark them with `[ObservableProperty]` and with `[NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(CreateFileCommand))]` but it doesn't work

Comment: You may have to rename the method to `private async Task OnCreateFileAsync()`. That's how it is shown in the documentation (which you should read yourself).

Comment: @Clemens Thank you, you were right. Name of method actually is important which I didn't know about. Also I had a problem with multiple command execution because I was able only to execute command once. So I added `[RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(ValuesAreNotEmpty), AllowConcurrentExecutions = true)]` and after that I can execute command multiple times

Comment: The latter is an indication that something is wrong with your OnCreateFileAsync method. Does the returned Task ever complete?

Comment: @Clemens Yup, the task was never going to complete because in finally block the while(true) method was called. I have already changed it and now I don't need `AllowConcurrentExecutions`. Thank you for help.